# fk column created in child entity with ManyToOne in parent for InheritanceType.JOINED

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, many-to-one

I'm having a problem with Hibernate entities inheritance where it creates a copy of fk column of a many-to-one relation without updating it.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Vehicle {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vehicle")
    private Set<Human> owner;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Integer age;

    @ManyToOne
    private Vehicle vehicle;
}

@Data
@Entity
public class Human extends Person {
    private String fullName;
}
```

With this entities it creates:

```sql
    
    create table human (
       full_name varchar(255),
        id bigint not null,
        vehicle_id bigint,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
    
    create table person (
       id bigint not null auto_increment,
        age integer,
        vehicle_id bigint,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
    
    create table vehicle (
       id bigint not null auto_increment,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
    
    alter table human 
       add constraint FKqctp8ycdo4mm7fsou0v4jalx3 
       foreign key (id) 
       references person (id)
    
    alter table person 
       add constraint FKgo297ke05qjubymwq6unmcnot 
       foreign key (vehicle_id) 
       references vehicle (id)
```

[image: ER model]

Why it declares Human.vehicle_id? I don't need it and hibernate dosn't sync it with Person.vehicle_id. The worst part is when hibernate Join Human with Vehicle it check Human.vehicle_id = Vehicle.id
How can I resolve this issue? I can't change InheritanceType because it will be huge migration.

Test case:

```java
final var car = Vehicle.builder().build();
        vehiclesRepo.save(car);
        final var mario = Human.builder()
                .fullName("Mario Rossi")
                .age(20)
                .vehicle(car)
                .build();
        humansRepo.save(mario);
```

```
Vehicle
id|
--+
 1|

Person
id|age|vehicle_id|
--+---+----------+
 2| 20|         1|

Human
full_name  |id|vehicle_id|
-----------+--+----------+
Mario Rossi| 2|          |
```

```sql
-- generated query for findAll

    select
        human0_.id as id1_1_,
        human0_1_.age as age2_1_,
        human0_1_.vehicle_id as vehicle_3_1_,
        human0_.full_name as full_nam1_0_ 
    from
        human human0_ 
    inner join
        person human0_1_ 
            on human0_.id=human0_1_.id

    select
        vehicle0_.id as id1_2_0_ 
    from
        vehicle vehicle0_ 
    where
        vehicle0_.id=?

    select
        owner0_.vehicle_id as vehicle_3_0_0_,
        owner0_.id as id2_0_0_,
        owner0_.id as id1_1_1_,
        owner0_1_.age as age2_1_1_,
        owner0_1_.vehicle_id as vehicle_3_1_1_,
        owner0_.full_name as full_nam1_0_1_,
        vehicle1_.id as id1_2_2_ 
    from
        human owner0_ 
    inner join
        person owner0_1_ 
            on owner0_.id=owner0_1_.id 
    left outer join
        vehicle vehicle1_ 
            on owner0_1_.vehicle_id=vehicle1_.id 
    where
        owner0_.vehicle_id=?
```

`owner0_.vehicle_id=?` here is where it fails the join because vehicle_id in human table is never populated, in this test scenario it's a bit better than real one because it actually made the join right and fails only in where conditions, in real use case it just use `on 1=1` in join.

Comment: have you tried " @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "any_specific_any_super_fk")) " for Human class? Having in mind you put the @JoinColumn with the same FK for Person.vehicle

Comment: @DannyBriskin I tried to add explicit PrimaryKeyJoinClumn in Human and JoinColumn in Person.vehicle but the result is exacly the same. Human is created with vehicle_id

Answer (score 1):

There is a discrepancy in database/system design. If only Humans can be Vehicle owners - you need to move Vehicle field into Human class (it solves your issue). Or (in case all Persons can do it) - you need to change Set{Human} to Set{Person} (it solves the issue too)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I didn't add other classes and field. In vehicle there are other fields of implantation of person, like pilot(assume it robot only to match original schema) and I need to query person directly. My first implementation did use your approach but I had some issues with few queries that have to retrieve person. I'll try to update with more details if I can create the equivalent of the rial impl

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the vehicle_id in children tables the association in Vehicle must use Person as base type explicitly in field type or using OneToMany.targetEntity
[image: example]

This resolve my problem partially because it added Robot amoung owners, I don't need that. I can use a discriminator column with a @Where condition or leave children vehicle_id and sync it programatically.